# Flashing message using Flask up task completion

Tags: python, flask

I'm still new to Flask and I am trying to build a flask app that flashes status as and when tasks are complete

`

```
app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():

    form = ReusableForm(request.form)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']

        if form.validate():
            Reports1 = RunReport1()
            flash('Report 1 run successfully')
            Report2 = RunReport2()
            flash('Report 2 run successfully')
    return render_template('run.html', form=form)'
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to flash messages without rendering the html page each time. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Jinja rendering action happens on the server so if you want your page to update dynamically you need to use Javascript/XHR/AJAX to pass information between your front end & back end. If you want to "push" information to the client dynamically you need a websockets connection

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Flask without roundtrip to the system. You have to use [content streaming](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#streaming-contents). For this you have to use [`stream_with_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#streaming-with-context) for the response.

```
@app.route("/")
def root():
    reports = ["Reports1", "Reports2"]

    def generate_output():
        for i in range(0, len(reports)):
            report = reports[i]
            template = '<p>{{ report }}.</p>'
            context = {'report': report}
            yield render_template_string(template, **context)
            time.sleep(5)

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate_output()))
```

So this will update the response till server side complete its tasks. Normally this is used for long running processes. Refer the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#streaming-contents).

Hope this helps!